# org-open-at-point (follow link) works for .org file, but not .org_archive

Tags: org-mode

I had a link to a headline in another `org` file that worked fine, but then I archived that subtree. I thought that updating the file to reflect the "`_archive`" part of the name would work, but `C-c C-o` does not work for such files. It does for `.org` files.

That is:

```
[[file:notes.org::*test%20heading%20here][this link works when the heading is there]]

[[file:notes.org_archive::*test%20heading%20here][this one doesn't, even if the heading is there]]
```

I'm on Windows and it looks like emacs is looking for another program to handle a `org_archive` file. How can I tell emacs/org-mode to treat `.org_archive` files like `.org` files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to associate `.org_archive` extension with `org-mode` by adding this to your init file:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org_archive\\'" . org-mode))
```

Emacs doesn't match file extensions in a fuzzy manner, so having an extension that just starts with `.org` isn't enough. If `.org_archive` isn't the only extension you're interested in, you can change the regular expression to match more variations.